# Creating a dictionary from a text file on python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am fairly new to dictionaries and i am trying to get around from creating one from an input text file test.txt on the following format:

```
A: B, C
B: C, D
C: D
D: C
E: F
F: C
```

ideally i would like to create a dictionary like the following:

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
             'B': ['C', 'D'],
             'C': ['D'],
             'D': ['C'],
             'E': ['F'],
             'F': ['C']}
```

this is what i got but i am stuck as i cannot get a dictionary like the one a bove which will be made to represent a graph:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def createDirectory():
new_graph = defaultdict(list)
fin = 'test.txt'
with open(fin,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        x = line.split(':')
        new_graph[x[0]] = x[1]
return new_graph
```

the above gives me a lists as follows:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': ' B, C', 'C': ' D', 'B': ' C, D', 'E': ' F', 'D': ' C', 'F': ' C'})
```

edit: i got a bit closer by using:

```
new_graph[x[0]].append(x[1])
```

however, i am not sure how to get rid of the blank spaces and to get the order right so that i get A,B,C,D,E,F and not A,C,B,E,E,F

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [' B, C'], 'C': [' D'], 'B': [' C, D'], 'E': [' F'], 'D': [' C'], 'F': [' C']})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `defaultdict`, those are for when you need to accumulate something - your text file contains the `dict` fully formed, you just need to parse it correctly.

One-liner (okay, two) version:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    d = {k:[x.strip() for x in v.split(',')] for k,v in (line.split(':') for line in f)}

d
Out[56]: 
{'A': ['B', 'C'],
 'B': ['C', 'D'],
 'C': ['D'],
 'D': ['C'],
 'E': ['F'],
 'F': ['C']}
```

In case the above dict comprehension is intimidating, it's just a terse way of writing:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        k,v = line.split(':')
        for x in v.split(','):
            x = x.strip()
            d.setdefault(k,[]).append(x)
```

Comment: python to its best! any idea why it prints out on that odd order? I get keys A,C,B,E,D,F where i would expect keys to be : A,B,C,D,E,F. edit: intimidating and awesome

Comment: dictionaries are arbitrarily ordered, you cannot depend on the ordering.

Comment: You can use OrderedDict if you want the keys to be ordered.

Comment: 99% (really, more) of use cases don't need to enforce a given ordering of `dict` keys.  If you need it you should probably reexamine why.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for. You should use value.split(,) so that values will be split by the separator ',' and will return a list.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def createDirectory():
    new_graph = {}
    fin = 'test.txt'
    with open(fin,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            key,value = line.split(':')
            values = value.split(',')
            values = map(str.strip, values)
            new_graph[key] = values
    new_graph = OrderedDict(sorted(new_graph.items()))
    return new_graph
```

**Update**
Edited the answer to strip leading and trailing whitespaces and use OrderedDict

Comment: neat answer! will give this a try next

Comment: I updated the answer to use OrderedDict so that you can have ordered keys.

Comment: If you also want to sort the values, just replace new_graph[key] = values with new_graph[key] = sorted(values).